# What Do I Put into a Quote Vault?

Tags: raydium

I have a platform asset, which I'm using as tying mechanic between a stack of my apps, for login and rewards etc. The problem I am having is working out what to put into the OpenBook Vaults. For the VOX/SOL pairing I need to know how much VOX I should deposit into the Vase Vault, versus how much wSOL I should put into the Quote Vault. Also, concerning the Quote Vault, is that wrapped SOL that goes in there and if so where do I get that from?

Am I meant to wrap VOX tokens in SOL somehow? Do I put the LP tokens in there that I got for putting liquidity into the pool? Can anyone help on this?

VOX/SOL Pair
https://openbook-tools.dexlab.space/market/39UG4BKN3uQaU4tyRDDfE8nvkdb5VBoL1vEbwdhWSxEV

Base Vault:
4Xbv6oyTuJmonwMpDUfNSc6zeSwiK5GrZxcCVTTq45ET

Quote Vault:
7SnZvEQdyWu94Bu435hj7JHvn2yeZtskQUG8MUATF2RS

Raydium Pool:
https://raydium.io/liquidity/add/?coin0=DPfXjdh5zop5oAxDrtD9wVYv3jrer8uqbuArwUp6BAez&coin1=So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112

The VOIX Token:
https://solscan.io/token/DPfXjdh5zop5oAxDrtD9wVYv3jrer8uqbuArwUp6BAez

Answer (score 0):

This may only be a partial answer to your question, but wSOL is SOL wrapped in an spl-token account, similar to wrapped Eth on Ethereum. To get wrapped SOL, you can simply wrap it from a SOL wallet using the CLI:

```
$ spl-token wrap <SOL_AMOUNT>
Wrapping 10 SOL into <YOUR_TOKEN_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS>
```

You'll need to use that token account address to deposit your wrapped SOL into the vault.